# Unable to fread output of a remote php file

Tags: php

I am using the output of a php file on a remote server, to show content on my own web-site. I do not have access to modify files on the remote server.

The remote php file outputs java script like this:

```
document.write('<p>some text</p>');
```

If I enter the url in a browser I get the correct output. E.g:

```
https://www.remote_server.com/files/the.php?param1=12
```

I can show the output of the remote file on my website like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.remote_server.com/files/the.php?param1=12"></script>
```

But I would like to filter the output a bit before showing it.
Therefore I implemented a php file with this code:

```
function getRemoteOutput(){
    $file = fopen("https://www.remote_server.com/files/the.php?param1=12","r");
    $output = fread($file,1024);
    fclose($file);
    return $output;
}
```

When I call this function fopen() returns a valid handle, but fread() returns an empty string.
I have tried using file_get_contents() instead, but get the same result.

Is what I am trying to do possible?
Is it possible for the remote server to allow me to read the file via the browser, but block access from a php file?

Comment: does that page have anything in it :-|

Comment: you should try using `curl`

Comment: @FerozAkbar. Yes, it has contents. If I access it directly from a web boowser, I get text.

Comment: @GopakumarGopalan. Same result using curl.

Comment: can I see the code and the url you are trying?

Comment: @GopakumarGopalan You can see my code in the answer I posted below, but the URL is not mine to give.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$output` is only holding the 1st 1024 bytes of the url... (headers maybe?).
You will need to add a `while` not the "end of file" loop to concatenate the entire remote file.

PHP reference: [feof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php)

You can learn a lot more in the PHP description for the `fread` function.

PHP reference: [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php).

```
<?php
echo getRemoteOutput();
function getRemoteOutput(){
    $file = fopen("http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php","r");
    $output = "";
    while (!feof($file)){ // while not the End Of File
         $output.= fread($file,1024); //reads 1024 bytes at a time and appends to the variable as a string.
    }
return $output;
fclose($file);
}  

?>
```

In regards to your questions:

> Is what I am trying to do possible?

Yes this is possible.

> Is it possible for the remote server to allow me to read the file via
>   the browser, but block access from a php file?

I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is not the solution. I only used the one-line read to simplify the example. <br> I have used php files on my own domaine, and that works. The php file in your example also works, but the one that I really want to read just returns an empty string. <br>And it really is an empty string. No formatting, no header, just 0 byte.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the support team for the site I was trying to connect to. They told me that they do prevent access from php files.
So that seems to be the reason for my problems, and apparently I just cannot do what I tried to do.

For what it's worth, here is the code I used to test the various methods to read file output:

```
<?php
//$remotefile = 'http://www.xencomsoftware.net/configurator/tracker/ip.php';
$remotefile = "http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php";

function getList1(){
    global $remotefile;
    $output = file_get_contents($remotefile);
    return htmlentities($output);
}

function getList2(){
    global $remotefile;
    $file = fopen($remotefile,"r");
    $output = "";
    while (!feof($file)){            // while not the End Of File
        $output.= fread($file,1024); //reads 1024 bytes at a time and appends to the variable as a string.
        }
    fclose($file);
    return htmlentities($output);
}

function getList3(){
    global $remotefile;
    $ch = curl_init();                               // create curl resource
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remotefile);      // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //return the transfer as a string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);                        // $output contains the output string
    curl_close($ch);                                 // close curl resource to free up system resources

    return htmlentities($output);
}

function getList4(){
    global $remotefile;

    $r = new HttpRequest($remotefile, HttpRequest::METH_GET);
    try {
        $r->send();
        if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
          $output = $r->getResponseBody();
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    return htmlentities($output);
}

function dumpList($ix, $list){
    $len = strlen($list);
    echo "<p><b>--- getList$ix() ---</b></p>";
    echo "<div>Length: $len</div>";
    for ($i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++) {
        echo "$i: $list[$i] <br>";
    }
//    echo "<p>$list</p>";
}


dumpList(1, getList1());  // doesn't work! You cannot include/requre a remote file.
dumpList(2, getList2());

dumpList(3, getList3());
dumpList(4, getList4());
?>
```

Comment: As it turned out the support team did not quite know what they were talking about. They do not prevent access from php files, but they do prevent any access from other countries. And since my web-hotel is located abroad, it gets blocked. So now I have placed a php file on a domestic server, and my web-site uses that php to access the data.